# System of ODEs with stochastic process

Tags: python, ode, stochastic-ode

Consider system of ordinary differential equations

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=\sigma(y-x)\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=\rho x-y-xz\\
\frac{dz}{dt}&=xy-\beta z
\end{align}
$$

with $\sigma=10$, $\rho=28$ and $\beta=\frac{8}{3}$ and with initial condition $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1.508870, -1.531271, 25.246091)$

I am trying to embed the system in a stochastic environment by adding an exponentially colored noise process to the parameter $\sigma$: $$d\tilde{\sigma}_t=-\alpha\tilde{\sigma}_tdt+\gamma dW_t,\sigma_t=10+\tilde{\sigma}_t$$

I got following system of stochastic differential equations

$$
\begin{align}
dx_t&=(10+\tilde{\sigma}_t)(y_t-x_t)dt\\
dy_t&=(\rho x_t-y_t-x_tz_t)dt\\
dz_t&=(x_ty_t-\beta z_t)dt\\
d\tilde{\sigma}_t&=-\alpha\tilde{\sigma}_tdt+\gamma dW_t
\end{align}
$$

and I want to analyze the strong and weak order of convergence of the Euler-Maruyama scheme. Does the stochastic system have exact solution? If not, what is the best way of acquiring accurate solution that I can use to calculate errors agains numerical approximations in Python?

I was thinking about generating a path of $\tilde{\sigma}_t$ first and using `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` to solve the rest of ODEs. However, it seems like time step used in `solve_ivp` is adjusted and `t` passed to `fun` is not integer so I am not sure how to combine pregenerated path with the rest of ODEs.

Another approach I had in mind was to solve the system of SDEs as is but I am not aware of Python libraries that can solve the system of SDEs and I believe that I need to use the same path for both the reference solution and the numerical approximation when calculating errors.

Comment: *but I am not aware of Python libraries that can solve the system of SDEs* – Blatant self advertisement: [JiTCSDE](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcsde) can. The method [`pin_noise`](https://jitcsde.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0/#_jitcsde.jitcsde.pin_noise) might be helpful for your estimation purposes as far as I can tell at a first glance, possibly together with fixing the seed.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for the suggestion. It looks promising and I will give it a try.